# How to test retries and failures in resque-retry and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, resque, resque-retry

I am trying to write a spec that tests the retry functionality of resque-retry and I can not seem to get the tests to hit the binding.pry's correctly. Is there a way to test this functionality using rspec 3 so I can verify they are functioning as intended?

This is a request spec and I am trying to simulate a live request via fixtures, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get the job to retry.

```
gem 'resque', require: 'resque/server'
gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web'
gem 'resque-scheduler'
gem 'resque-retry'
gem 'resque-lock-timeout'
```

I am using [resque_rspec](https://github.com/leshill/resque_spec), and trying this [testing strategy](http://unknownerror.org/opensource/resque/resque/q/stackoverflow/5141378/how-to-bridge-the-testing-using-resque-with-rspec-examples).

**Partial Spec**

```
it 'retries it' do
  stub_request(:any, /.*api.bigcartel.*/).to_return(body: '{}', status: 200)
  @order_shipped_json['order']['originator_id'] = @provider_order
  post "/hook/shops/#{@shop.id}", @order_shipped_json.to_json, format: :json
  ResqueSpec.perform_all(queue_name)
  ???
end
```

**Queue Job**

```
class QueueHook
  extend Resque::Plugins::LockTimeout
  extend Resque::Plugins::Retry
  extend QueueLock
  extend QueueLogger

  @queue = AppSettings.queues[:hook_queue_name].to_sym
  @lock_timeout = 600
  @retry_exceptions = [QueueError::LockFailed]
  @retry_limit = 600
  @retry_delay = 1

  class << self
    def perform(web_hook_payload_id, _whiplash_customer_id)
      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
      @web_hook_payload = WebHookPayload.find(web_hook_payload_id)
      klass_constructor
      @hook.process_event
    end

    def identifier(_web_hook_payload_id, whiplash_customer_id)
      "lock:integration_hook:#{whiplash_customer_id}"
    end

    def after_perform_delete_webhook(_web_hook_payload_id, _whiplash_customer_id)
      @web_hook_payload.destroy
    end

    private

    ...
  end
end
```

**Queue Job Modules**

```
module QueueLogger
  def before_perform_log_job(*args)
    Rails.logger.info "[Resque][#{self}] running with #{args.inspect}..."
  end

  def on_failure_log_job(*args)
    message = "[Resque][#{self}] failed with #{args.inspect}..."
    run_counters
    Rails.logger.info message_builder(message)
  end

  private

  def run_counters
    @num_attempts += retry_attempt
    @all_attempts += retry_limit
  end

  def message_builder(message)
    return message unless @num_attempts
    return message += " Retrying (attempt ##{@num_attempts + 1})" if @num_attempts < @all_attempts
    message += ' Giving up.'
    message
  end
end

module QueueLock
  def loner_enqueue_failed(*args)
    Rails.logger.info "[Resque][#{self}] is already enqueued: #{args.inspect}..."
  end

  def lock_failed(*)
    raise QueueError::LockFailed
  end
end
```

Comment: You have to use exception handlers.

Comment: do you have an example spec?

Comment: dont use rescue retry , catch exceptions and retry in the code

Comment: do you have examples because everything I have read says to avoid rescue catches like you're stating at all costs.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to test? I think you are trying to do a system test when a unit test would be more appropriate.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to test the retry counter, and module code.  The only way I could fire it was to add the raise Queue::Lock error line manually in the perform

Comment: I would argue that there is no need to test functionality provided by a gem. You should only test your own code.

Comment: what about the code in the modules? how can we prove that the retries are actually working?  do you have an idea on how to test for this?

Comment: +1 @spickermann, It is a common approach NOT to test gem's functionality, only yours. Gem are usually already shipped with tests

Comment: FWIW you may be running up against rspecs transactional nature. I know this has made me basically give up testing sidekiq, which uses resque, in apps that run rails 4. Suppossedly this has been addressed in rails 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the specific failure you want to test retries for comes from this hook you implemented.

```
def lock_failed(*)
  raise QueueError::LockFailed
end
```

We need to trigger this. [Here](https://github.com/lantins/resque-lock-timeout/blob/master/lib/resque/plugins/lock_timeout.rb#L215) is where it gets used in the plugin. Since you're using a lock timeout it looks like we want to stub `.acquire_lock_algorithm!`. This is dangerous since this method is part of the plugin's internal api. Keep it in mind when you upgrade the plugin.

```
it 'retries it' do
  stub_request(:any, /.*api.bigcartel.*/).to_return(body: '{}', status: 200)

  allow(QueueHook).to receive(:acquire_lock_algorithm!).and_return(false, true)

  @order_shipped_json['order']['originator_id'] = @provider_order
  post "/hook/shops/#{@shop.id}", @order_shipped_json.to_json, format: :json

  ResqueSpec.perform_all(queue_name)
end
```

This spec should now be failing with `Failure/Error: raise QueueError::LockFailed`. Since that's expected we can set an expectation.

```
it 'retries it' do
  stub_request(:any, /.*api.bigcartel.*/).to_return(body: '{}', status: 200)

  allow(QueueHook).to receive(:acquire_lock_algorithm!).and_return(false, true)

  @order_shipped_json['order']['originator_id'] = @provider_order
  post "/hook/shops/#{@shop.id}", @order_shipped_json.to_json, format: :json

  expect {
    ResqueSpec.perform_all(queue_name)
  }.to raise_error(QueueError::LockFailed)
end
```

The spec should now be passing unless you have set `ResqueSpec.inline = true`. If you have then set it to false for this spec. It will be easier to follow.

If resque-retry is working then the job's failure should have resulted in the job being re-enqueued to ResqueSpec. We can add an expectation for that. `expect(ResqueSpec.queues[queue_name]).to be_present`. Not we can run the jobs again. We mocked the second return value of `acquire_lock_algorithm!` to be true so the job should succeed this time.

Since we want to test the counters lets add readers for them

```
module QueueLogger
  attr_reader :all_attempts, :num_attempts
end
```

And then finish up the spec...

```
it 'retries it' do
  stub_request(:any, /.*api.bigcartel.*/).to_return(body: '{}', status: 200)

  allow(QueueHook).to receive(:acquire_lock_algorithm!).and_return(false, true)

  @order_shipped_json['order']['originator_id'] = @provider_order
  post "/hook/shops/#{@shop.id}", @order_shipped_json.to_json, format: :json

  # Failing
  expect {
    ResqueSpec.perform_all(queue_name)
  }.to raise_error(QueueError::LockFailed)
  expect(ResqueSpec.queues[queue_name]).to be_present

  # Retrying
  ResqueSpec.perform_all(queue_name)
  expect(QueueHook.num_attempts).to eq(2)
  ... # Whatever else you want to test.
end
```

If you want to test the logging specifically you stub them and set expectations regarding what they are called with. That should do it, I have a simplified version running on my own machine. If not we might have to get into the details of your test and Resque configs.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes-

1) As mentioned by others, you probably want to separate the `resque` callbacks from their functionality. That is, test that the `retries` are firing, but also separately test that they function as expected. You may want to separate those into two separate tests.

2) For checking that they are firing, I think you are looking for [class doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double) in RSpec 3.

You will need to instatiate the double and then raise an exception ([docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error)). This will allow you to see if your `retries` are being called, and how many times they have been called ([docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts)).

So, for example,

```
it "retries on exception n number of times" do
  queue_hook = class_double("QueueHook")
  expect(queue_hook).to have_received(:on_failure_log_job).exactly(n).times
  allow(queue_hook).to receive(:perform).and_raise(ExceptionClass, "Exception message")
  queue_hook.perform(payload_id, customer_id)
end
```

There's a fair bit going on, so I can't implement locally, but hopefully this can help you get going in the right direction.